# I'm having really difficult time with my .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having really difficult time with my .htaccess file

(Apache) httpd.conf: The following are uncommented:

```
mod_rewrite
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

My document root / directory:

```
DocumentRoot "f:/www"
<Directory "f:/www">
```

My index.html file is in:

```
F:\www\portfolio2
```

My .htaccess file is in:

```
F:\www\portfolio2
```

Inside my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^portf/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) index.html?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

The directory:

```
F:\www\portfolio2\portf
```

does not exist, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't need to, right?

Inside my index.html :

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

When I test the url:

```
http://localhost/portfolio2/portf/qweasd
```

My console logs the following errors / warnings:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    bootstrap.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    javascript.js:1

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
"http://localhost/portfolio2/portf/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css".
                                            qweasd:20

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
"http://localhost/portfolio2/portf/css/portfolio.css".
                                            qweasd:21
```

From What I see, it thinks I have a directory named "portf", which I don't.

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention, the page loads but not the CSS, JavaScript, etc.

**EDIT2**: **Solved**. I added: `RewriteBase /portfolio2/` to `.htaccess` and I'm using relative URL's throughout my site. I also replaced `rel="stylesheet"` and the styles are now being applied. Then I added `<base href="/portfolio2/">` 
 in `<head>` before CSS and JavaScript imports. Cheers!

Comment: Okay, just my random thoughts, and I'm guessing you don't care so much about the JS syntax messages.With the directory question, then you've only told the server to fetch resources from a different place - the browser doesn't know what's going on in the background. For the browser console to report anything different then the URL displayed in the address bar would have to be different, and if you wanted that to be different then your rewrite would need to be a redirect [R=301]. (I think). I'm assuming the rewrite is working and you're just curious re' the console log.

Comment: @Cheddar Ok I just changed: `RewriteRule ^portf/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) index.html?p=$1 [R=301,NC,L]`, Now I get `Access forbidden! 403`. Also, my URL went into file mode instead of an actual URL: `http://localhost/F:/www/portfolio2/index.html?p=qweasd`

Comment: Okay, you've added info' to the question now, so I guess you are more concerned with the JS and CSS not working rather than just curious about the console message about the URL. Well, ignore the redirect bit for now, and revert back to what you had, and, regarding the CSS, then try removing the "rel="stylesheet" from the tags which you have, and try it again.

Comment: @Cheddar Right, CSS error taken care of, now I just get the same errors for the JavaScript: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    bootstrap.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <    javascript.js:1`

Comment: Okay, good; I'm glad the CSS is working now at least. The "Uncaught SyntaxError" can be caused by a few things it seems, but try using the fully qualified URL for the location of the JS scripts, rather than just the relative URLs which you have, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Cheddar Sorry, the CSS error went away but the page loaded without styles being applied. Also, I used fully qualified URLs for the JavaScript but then got another error from inside my `javascript.js` ajax request. It also wanted me to use a fully qualified URL for the `URL:` property. I don't see using FQ URLs all over my website as an option. Is that absolutely necessary?

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd actually seen a question elsewhere regarding the FQ JS urls, and in that case it worked okay, but maybe in your case it's not suitable or applicable. Hmm, well, I don't seem to have made too much progress for you, but hopefully someone more knowledgeable can assist. Best wishes.

Comment: @Cheddar Solved, see edit above. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it working.